# CakePHP 3.x optional language routing

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating a multi language site. I want it to be in english when no language parameter is set and a different language when a language parameter is set.

My routing looks as follows:

`$routes->connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*');`

The issue is as follows:

When I visit `www.mydomain.com/users/login` it works fine.

When I visit `www.mydomain.com/fr/users/login` it works fine (in french).

But when I visit `www.mydomain.com/users/login/1` where the `1` is a custom named parameter I want to parse, it naturally thinks that `users` is the language and `login` is my controller and `1` is my action.

I'm aware that if I force there to always be a language parameter this would no longer be an issue but I don't want the english version to be at `www.mydomain.com/en/`. I want it to be at `www.mydomain.com`.

Is this achievable? Is there a way to ignore the language parameter if it's not `fr` or `es` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a regular expression for matching route elements. So you need something similar to

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:language/:controller/:action/*', 
    [], 
    ['language' => 'fr|es']
);
```

Consult the CakePHP manual / API for more details.

Comment: Will this essentially use regular `/:controller/:action/*` routing if `:language` isn't set to `fr` or `es`? @ADmad

Comment: @Cellydy if there's no language prefix, the route definition in this answer simply won't be a match. If you want standard fallback routes [you need to add them](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration) otherwise the url `/controller/action/blah` will be a 404.

Comment: @ADmad Thanks for the help!